# Actions in Webdrivers: an example of a working set of data

Tags: selenium, firefox, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, geckodriver

I am banging my head against the [webdriver specs](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html#dfn-perform-actions) to get actions happening.

**NOTE: I am after the payload to send to the webdriver**. I am not after a bunch of lines of code to make up a set of actions. *I am interested in the payload to send to the action endpoints.*

I am reading the specs, but I am having problems understanding what *exactly* I have to pass, and how, to the web driver's endpoint to make anything happen. I am trying to get it to work with Firefox, as Chrome doesn't implement them at all for now.

Are you able to provide a couple of examples of actions to get me going? Something that *works* and to build upon?

Answer (score 0):

See if this code helps :

```
     WebElement main_link= driver.findElement(By.linkText("Main_Link"));

     Actions action = new Actions(driver);

     action.moveToElement(main_link).build().perform();

     driver.findElement(By.linkText("sub_link")).click();
```

Comment: Please note that I am after the _payload_. That is, I am after how to interact with the Webdriver using `curl`, not an API. Clarifying this further in my question