# Improve selenium code's speed

Tags: python, performance, selenium, browser, selenium-chromedriver

I'm using Selenium in python to test a data table (not really a html table, combined by multiple divs)

That's what my table looks like:

```
<div class="products">
    <div class="product">
        <span class="original-price">20$</span>
        <span class="discounted-price">10$</span>            
    </div>

    <div class="product">
        <span class="price">20$</span>
    </div>

    ...
</div>
```

There are multiple products, some has discounted price.

This is my script:

```
products = self.driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.products > div')
for product in products:
    found_price = True
    try:
        original_price = product.find_element_by_css_selector('.original-price').text
        reduced_price = product.find_element_by_css_selector('.discounted-price').text
    except NoSuchElementException:
        try:
            original_price = product.find_element_by_css_selector('.price').text
            reduced_price = original_price
        except NoSuchElementException:
            found_price = False

    if found_price: check_price(original_price, reduced_price)
```

But my script runs very slowly. It sends a lot of request "remote_connection" each time the "find_element_by_css_selector" called like this one:

```
2018-02-27 13:48:08 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:62147/session/14902b71a0f812fa74f81524f0eb1386/elements {"using": "css selector", "sessionId": "14902b71a0f812fa74f81524f0eb1386", "value": ".products > div .original-price"}
2018-02-27 13:48:08 [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
```

Any ideas to improve its performance ?

Thanks !

Comment: Can you update the question why you feel `my script runs very slowly` or some evidence on `sends a lot of request "remote_connection" each time the "find_element_by_css_selector" called`?

Comment: @DebanjanB I updated my question with the logs of selenium. Thanks

Comment: But because my table has one hundred rows so there are about 200 - 300 lines with "remote_connection". I wonder if it is normal or may I optimize that.

Answer (score 0):

One of the parameters of the remove WebDriver is `keep_alive`. As the doc says:

```
keep_alive - Whether to configure remote_connection.RemoteConnection to use
             HTTP keep-alive. Defaults to False.
```

Keeping the connection alive would improve the speed as it does not have to connect on every find request.

Comment: Thank you ! Do you know how to set keep_alive = True ? 
This is my init but it doesn't work if I add keep_alive as an argument of chrome_options.

    chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
    chrome_options.add_argument('headless')
    chrome_options.add_argument('no-sandbox')
    chrome_options.add_argument('keep-alive')
    self.driver = webdriver.Chrome(chrome_options=chrome_options)

Comment: Seems like chromedriver does not support keepalive

Answer (score 0):

It is still inconslusive why you feel your *script runs very slowly*. As you mentioned your code *sends a lot of request `remote_connection` each time the `find_element_by_css_selector`* is exactly the way as it is defined in the [**`WebDriver-W3C Candidate Recommendation`**](https://w3c.github.io/webdriver/webdriver-spec.html).

A small test with the `Search Box` of `Google Home Page` i.e. `https://www.google.co.in` with all the major variants of *WebDrivers* and *Web Browsers* reveals that :

- Each time you search a webelement in the *HTML DOM* as follows :

  ```
  product.find_element_by_css_selector('.original-price')
  ```
- The following request is generated :

  ```
  [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: POST http://127.0.0.1:62147/session/14902b71a0f812fa74f81524f0eb1386/elements {"using": "css selector", "sessionId": "14902b71a0f812fa74f81524f0eb1386", "value": ".products > div .original-price"}
  [selenium.webdriver.remote.remote_connection] DEBUG: Finished Request
  ```
- On a successful search the following response is sent back from the *Web Browser* :

  ```
  webdriver::server   DEBUG   <- 200 OK {"value":{"element-6066-11e4-a52e-4f735466cecf":"6e35faa4-233f-400c-a6c7-6a66b54a69e5"}}
  ```

You can find a detailed discussion in [*Values returned by webdrivers*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369301/values-returned-by-webdrivers/48381192#48381192)

- However there will be some deviation in the performance depending on the [*Locator Strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890) you use.
- There have been quite some experiments and benchmarking about the performance aspects of the locators. You can find some discussions here :

  - [**Locator Performance Metrics using Selenium**](https://gist.github.com/santiycr/963821)
  - [**Css Vs. X Path**](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/32-xpath-vs-css)
  - [**Css Vs. X Path, Under a Microscope**](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/33-xpath-vs-css-revisited)
  - [**Css Vs. X Path, Under a Microscope (Part 2)**](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/34-xpath-vs-css-revisited-2)
  - [**What is the difference between css-selector & Xpath? which is better(according to performance & for cross browser testing)?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16788310/what-is-the-difference-between-css-selector-xpath-which-is-betteraccording-t/16794683)