# How to edit and print the specification of webelement using Log4j?

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, log4j, selenium-chromedriver

In my testing framework I've got a method called 'isElementDisplayed'.

```
public boolean isElementDisplayed(WebElement element) {
    try {
        logger.info(element);
        return element.isDisplayed();
    } catch (NoSuchElementException e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

After execute logger write to file specification of webelement like:

> [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (hash)] -> id: idofelement]

How can I make it shorter just like:

> [id: idofelement]

It there any possibility to cut unnecessary beginning?

Comment: Or in the best case to get: [chrome -> id: idofelement]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the discussion [Values returned by webdrivers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369301/values-returned-by-webdrivers/48381192#48381192) within the **Browser Specific Implementation** section:

A small test was carried out with the `Search Box` of `Google Home Page` i.e. `https://www.google.co.in` with `ChromeDriver` and here was the observation:

- **`ChromeDriver`** - **`OSS`** :

  ```
  [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (0d24fd038bde751b1e411711271c3e69)] -> name: q]
  [[ChromeDriver: chrome on XP (0d24fd038bde751b1e411711271c3e69)] -> name: q]
  ```

So as you can observe from the field details of the concerned **`value`** field returned is in similar pattern and till the `WebDriver` variant passes the correct reference to user and is not configurable/editable.

Further, if you want to edit (and then print) the **value** you have to write a sparate method for regex handling.